Is there a way to calculate the habitable zone distances of a star?
What would you need to calculate the habitable zone distances of a star? I am aware of the Stefan-Boltzmann Law and Wein's Law to calculate the Luminosity of the star, and that the flux decreases with the square of the distance due to the inverse square law. However, how do I relate these properties? How do I say, find the habitable zone distance of a star. Mainly, I am confused on how the inverse square law changes the temperatures at distances away from the star. Any formulas would help.

I think it's answered in ASE. Just look for the distances where effective temperature is in say $[-20,+20]{}^\circ C$ range, so that it's possible for liquid water to coexist. You also may need to assume greenhouse gasses in planet for raising temperature and so broadening habitable zone (maybe vulcanic activity too).

Thanks, I think that answers it. By effective temperature you mean the equilibrium temperature, right?

Wikipedia has a page on Effective Temperature.
